# Combining two data types in one column

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I am reading an excel file into Python which has a column with dates formatted as a string.  Some of the cells contain a dash instead of dates.  Currently I am converting the dashes to blanks and then formatting the column to a datetime column. However, I would like to have the cells with dashes read "OPEN" instead of blank.  Is this possible?

```
df_Fin['Trade Term Date'] = np.where(df_Fin['Modified Term Date'] == '-', '', 
                                     df_Fin['Modified Term Date'])

df_Fin['Trade Term Date'] = [time.date() for time in df_Fin['Trade Term Date']]
```

Comment: Did you try replacing the dashes with "OPEN" instead of an empty string?

Comment: Yep, did that first, and I got an error saying 'str' object has no attribute 'date'

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert 'OPEN' into a date, but you the map a lambda function to the list:

```
    from datetime import datetime as d.strptime
    
    #This tranforms x into a date if x has not the value 'OPEN'
    date_format = "%d.%m.%Y" #Change this to your format. d = day, m = month, y = year
    transform = lambda x: d.strptime(x, date_format) if x != 'OPEN' else x

    #This applies the Function to the complete list
    df['Trade Term Date'] = list(map(transform, df['Trade Term Date']))
```

I created a little dataframe with this kind of values:

```
       Trade Term Date
0  2020-03-12 00:00:00
1  2020-03-12 00:00:00
2  2020-03-12 00:00:00
3  2020-03-12 00:00:00
4  2020-03-12 00:00:00
5                 OPEN
6  2020-03-12 00:00:00
7                 OPEN
```

You can apply any function you need in the lambda expression.

But a little problem persists. If you transform some data into a date, the type of your column won't be date and therefore the data won't be safed as date. This is due to the nump-memory process, where every element in the column needs to have the same data-type and 'OPEN' can't have the type date.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I like having the column as a date type, but I can work around that if it is the only way to include a string in some cells.  However, this line of code produced the following error: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Ah. Sorry i forgot. It skips the Values. I edit my anser